# renderer in series block in the chart extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

I would like to change color of chart in extjs type ='pie'. 
Can I use renderer in the series block please see the example:

```
.....    },
                series : [ {
                    type : 'bar',
                    axis : 'bottom',
                    gutter : 0,
                    groupGutter : 0,
                    yField : this.fields,
                    title : this.fieldTitles,
                    stacked : true,
                    fill: true,
                    scope: this,
                    renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                        var color = this.fieldColors[index];
                        return Ext.apply(attr, {
                            fill: color
                        });
                    },.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a custom renderer, you can use the colorSet property for your series.

```
series: [{
    colorSet: this.fieldColors,
    ...
}]
```

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie-cfg-colorSet

Comment: This is only for pie chart